# Angular 9: component template is checked before constructor runs

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, getter

Just migrated from Angular 8 to Angular 9 (without IVY) and caught strange errors saying that services injected in component are undefined in getters.
I debugged a little bit and found out that the getter is being called before constructor.

I'm curious how could this be.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    templateUrl: './some-component.pug'
})
export class SomeComponent {
    get someProp () {
        console.log('Getter called', { ...this.someService }); // 'Getter called' {}
        return this.someService.some;
    }

    constructor (private someService: SomeService) { console.log('Constructor called') }

}

// some-component.pug
{{ someProp }}
```

This will produce an error 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

**UPDATE**
After further investigation I have found out that it happens only when I use 9th version of ngrx:

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think question mark would solve the error:

```
return this.someService?.some;
```

But you might want to try and use lifecycle hooks such as ngOnInit, because it is fired after the constructor.

Comment: as well as old `return this.someService && this.someService.some;`
but why is this happening in Angular 9?